# Iteration of Array in Array causes FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Tags: powershell

This extended Hello World example causes a FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray execption when accessing $greeting[1].

```
function array_hello ($planet){
    $array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    [void]$array.Add('hello')
    [void]$array.Add($planet)
    return $array
}

function planets_hallo ($planets){
    $greetings = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    foreach($planet in $planets){
        $hellos = array_hello ($planet)
        [void]$greetings.Add($hellos)
    }
    return $greetings
}

$planets = @('Mercur', 'World', 'Mars')
$greetings = planets_hallo ($planets)

foreach($greeting in $greetings){
    Write-Output("${greeting[0]} ${gretting[1]}")
    $greeting[0]
    $gretting[1]
}
```

And I can see in VS Code debugger that the values are as expected. How would I correctly iterate of array in arrays in Powershell ?

Comment: `${gretting[1]}` should be `${greeting[1]}`.

Comment: Do not use brackets on parameters. `$greetings = planets_hallo ($planets)` --> `$greetings = planets_hallo $planets`, `$hellos = array_hello ($planet)` --> `$hellos = array_hello $planet`. Also, fix the typo `$gretting`

Comment: Use `Set-StrictMode -version 'latest'` and you'll get error messages about mistyped variable names.

Comment: @vonPryz after setting strict mode powershell complains about not undefinde index variables

Comment: thanks. Of course ${greeting[1]} should be used. The Write-Output command is still empty than. $greeting[1] gives the right values

Comment: @Theo why should I leave the brackets away ?

Comment: Because it is [bad practice](https://serverfault.com/questions/819763/why-is-it-wrong-to-call-functions-with-parentheses-in-powershell/820149) to do so.

Comment: @Theo Thanks, I was afraid so. I am new to PS and that would be at least some similarity with others...

Comment: `${a[1]}` is _not_ the same as `$a[1]` - `${a[1]}` refers to a variable literally named `"a[1]"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for that. How would I correctly iterate over array of arrays with output and and with getting the value ?